# Evaluating Xpath in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, xpath

I'm trying to write a simple Scala function to extract data from a XML file using a XPath expression.

```
e.g.
<CATALOG>
  <PLANT>
    <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>4</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
    <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
  </PLANT>
<CATALOG>
```

```
val file = XML.loadFile(xmlFile)
val extractedData = file / "PLANT" / "COMMON"
```

when I hard code the above expression inside the function like the above 2 lines of code, it is working fine.

But, I want to pass the XPath expression to function, instead of hard coding

I tried the below

```
val xPath = """PLANT / COMMON"""
val extractedData = file / xPath
```

It's not working, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the XPath as Function should work:

```
val xPath = (ns:Elem) => ns \ "PLANT" \ "COMMON"
val extractedData = xPath(file)
```

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `foldLeft` and split your xpath:

```
import scala.xml.{NodeSeq, XML}

val xmlStr = """<CATALOG>
  | <PLANT>
  |   <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
  |   <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
  |   <ZONE>4</ZONE>
  |   <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
  |   <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
  |   <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
  | </PLANT>
  | </CATALOG>""".stripMargin

val file: NodeSeq = scala.xml.Utility.trim(XML.loadString(xmlStr))
val extractedData = file \ "PLANT" \ "COMMON"

val xPath = """PLANT / COMMON"""
val xPath = """PLANT / COMMON"""
val extractedDataViaXPath = xPath
  .split('/')
  .map(_.trim)
  .foldLeft(file)((acc, elt) => acc \ elt)

extractedData == extractedDataViaXPath // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [kantan.xpath](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.xpath)? This is basically what it does, if you look at the example on the github page.